# How to refer to another column of a df in the function inside lapply?

Tags: r, apply, lapply

sample df:

```
dat <- data.frame(position = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A"),
                  choice = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B"))

   position   choice   
1         A        A      
2         B        A      
3         B        B
4         A        B
5         B        A
6         A        B
```

I am trying to make another column in the dataframe so that if the two columns "position" and "choice" have the same alphabetic value, then the new column will say something, if not it will say something else:

```
   position   choice   value
1         A        A      ok
2         B        A      no
3         B        B      ok
4         A        B      no
5         B        A      no
6         A        B      no
```

So far I tried to make a new column with the same value of "choice" and then using lapply or sapply to replace the values with a conditional like this:

```
dat$value <- dat$choice

dat$choice[] <- lapply(dat$choice, function(x) 
                       ifelse(x == dat$position, "ok", x))
```

But it doesn't seem to work, there must be something wrong with the way I referred to "position". In fact it replaces all the values with the whole "position" column as a vector instead of the values one by one -- e.g. output: c("A", "A", "ok", "ok", "A", "ok") or viceversa c("ok", "ok", "B", "B", "ok", "B").

sapply, on the other hand, replaces everything with NAs.

Something else I've tried is this:

```
dat$value <- dat$choice

for(i in 1:length(dat_nat_last$choice)){
  if(dat$value [i] == dat$choice[i]) {
    dat$value [i] = "ok"
  }           
  else {
    dat$value [i] = "no"
  }
}
```

Which returns the error "Error in dat$value[i] == dat[i] : comparison of these types is not implemented"

Any suggestion?

Comment: You don't need `lapply` or loops for this. `==` is vectorized. Just do `dat$value <- dat$position == dat$choice`

Comment: On a side note, the reason you are getting the results you describe is that `ifelse` is vectorised. This means that the `lapply` is looping over each value of `dat$choice` and, at each value, then looping over all values in `dat$position`. If you want to use `ifelse` then you only need to do `dat$value <- ifelse(dat$choice == dat$position, "ok", "no")`

Comment: Thank you both, I can't believe it was so easy and I wasted so much time on it! I really need to finish my R basics once I'm done with this and can move on. Sorry for the stupid question and thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the character strings `"no"`and `"ok"` are required instead of logical values `FALSE` and `TRUE`, there is a nice alternative to `ifelse()` using `factor()` with the appropriate factor labels:

```
dat$value <- factor(dat$position == dat$choice, labels = c("no", "ok"))
dat
```

> ```
>   position choice value
> 1        A      A    ok
> 2        B      A    no
> 3        B      B    ok
> 4        A      B    no
> 5        B      A    no
> 6        A      B    no
> ```

#### Caveat

The sample data set `dat` has been created using `data.frame` which coerces *character* variables to *factor* by default.

*All* suggestions posted so far assume that the level sets of both factor columns `position` and `choice` are identical. Unfortunately, all solutions  will fail if there are different sets of letters in the columns (for what ever reason):

```
dat <- data.frame(position = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "D"),
                  choice = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C"))
dat$choice == dat$position
```

> Error in Ops.factor(dat$choice, dat$position) : level sets of factors are different

*One* possible solution is to convert the factors back to character for the comparison:

```
as.character(dat$position) == as.character(dat$choice)
```

> ```
> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> ```

So, the solution needs to be modified accordingly

```
dat$value <- factor(as.character(dat$position) == as.character(dat$choice), 
                    labels = c("no", "ok"))
dat
```

> ```
>   position choice value
> 1        A      A    ok
> 2        B      A    no
> 3        B      B    ok
> 4        A      B    no
> 5        B      A    no
> 6        D      C    no
> ```

Also the `ifelse()` approach needs to be modified:

```
dat$value <- ifelse(as.character(dat$position) == as.character(dat$choice), 
                    "ok", "no")
```